# Issue with category and brand listing

Tags: magento2, reindex, elasticsearch, category-listing

I'm facing an issue with Magento 2.4.x, the website is hosted on managed magento server. I'm facing issues with reindex even after reindexing all of the manufacturers are not listing on the front-end, we are using Amasty Improved layered navigation - Brands for the Brand Management. The same issue is faced on the category listing pages.

I already tried restarting elastic-search but it did not fix the issue.

Tried reindex and flush cache

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento "cache:clean"
php bin/magento cache:flush;redis-cli -h redis flushall;
/usr/share/stratus/cli cache.all.clear
/usr/share/stratus/cli autoscaling.reinit
```

We have 2 inventory sources (default & abc) and we have assigned products to the source abc. If we enable the configuration to display out of stock products the category and brand listing are working perfect. But if we do not allow Display Out of Stock products, the listings are not working.

If anybody have a solution for this issue. Please let me know.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and i got solution from the official Magento Docs:

1. Execute this query:

```
UPDATE catalog_eav_attribute AS cea
    INNER JOIN eav_attribute AS ea
        ON ea.attribute_id = cea.attribute_id
SET cea.is_filterable = 0, cea.is_filterable_in_search = 0
WHERE (cea.is_filterable = 1 OR cea.is_filterable_in_search = 1)
    AND frontend_input NOT IN ('boolean', 'multiselect', 'select', 'price');
```

2. Run the Catalog Search full reindex using the following command:

```
 bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
```

3. Clean cache by running

```
  bin/magento cache:clean
```

In the case of the Amasty Brands, update the brand attribute with these two settings: is_filterable = 0, is_filterable_in_search=0

For more info, please follow this guide:

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/troubleshooting/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-5-is-configured-but-search-page-does-not-load-with-fielddata-is-disabled...-error.html?lang=en